# pytest-mock assert_called_with failed for class function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I am planning to use pytest and pytest-mock for validating the Python code. Being a newbie, wrote a sample code to validate the mock on class and seeing failure. I am wondering what went wrong.

src/main.py

```
class Main(object):
    def __init__(self, my_var=None):
        self.var = my_var

    def internal_func(self, var=10):
        my_var = var + 20
        return my_var

    def test_func(self):
        val = self.internal_func(20)
        return val + 40
```

tests/test_main.py

```
    import pytest
    from pytest_mock import mocker
    from src.main import Main

    def new_func(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return 2

    def test_main_mock(mocker):
        mocker.patch.object(Main, 'internal_func')
        val = Main().test_func()
        assert Main.internal_func.assert_called_with(20)
```

It fails with the following error

```
    ======================================================================================== FAILURES ========================================================================================
    _____________________________________________________________________________________ test_main_mock _____________________________________________________________________________________

    mocker = <pytest_mock.MockFixture object at 0x7f34f490d8d0>

        def test_main_mock(mocker):
            mocker.patch.object(Main, 'internal_func')
            main = Main()
            val = main.test_func()
        #    assert val == 80
    >       assert Main.internal_func.assert_called_with(20)
    E       AssertionError: assert None
    E        +  where None = <bound method MagicMock.wrap_assert_called_with of <MagicMock name='internal_func' id='139865418160784'>>(20)
    E        +    where <bound method MagicMock.wrap_assert_called_with of <MagicMock name='internal_func' id='139865418160784'>> = <MagicMock name='internal_func' id='139865418160784'>.assert_called_with
    E        +      where <MagicMock name='internal_func' id='139865418160784'> = Main.internal_func

    tests/test_main.py:13: AssertionError
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The return_value or side_effect must be set before the patched func take effect

```
def test_main_mock(mocker):
    # mock internal_func of class Main
    mocked_internal_func = mocker.patch.object(Main, 'internal_func')
    # assign return_value or side_effect
    mocked_internal_func.return_value = -10
    # class instance
    ma = Main()
    val = ma.test_func()

    assert ma.internal_func.assert_called_with(20)
```

> Correction of mistake, the assert should not be used together with `assert_called_with`, they are independent assert.

```
    assert val == 30
    mocked_internal_func.assert_called
    ma.internal_func.assert_called_with(20)
    mocked_internal_func.assert_called_with(20)
```

Comment: Still the same error

    >       assert ma.internal_func.assert_called_with(20) 
    E       AssertionError: assert None
    E        +  where None = <bound method MagicMock.wrap_assert_called_with of <MagicMock name='internal_func' id='140714084186256'>>(20)
E        +    where <bound method MagicMock.wrap_assert_called_with of <MagicMock name='internal_func' id='140714084186256'>> = <MagicMock name='internal_func' id='140714084186256'>.assert_called_with
E        +      where <MagicMock name='internal_func' id='140714084186256'> = <src.main.Main object at 0x7ffa8d006390>.internal_func

Comment: mocker = <pytest_mock.MockFixture object at 0x7ffa8d00b6d0>

         def test_main_mock(mocker):
              m = mocker.patch.object(Main, 'internal_func')
              m.return_value = -10
              ma = Main()
              val = ma.test_func()
        >       assert ma.internal_func.assert_called_with(20)
         E       AssertionError: assert None

Comment: @suri, you are right, I mixed 2 assert together, that is why it is failed